# How can you prove that any two skew lines define a hyperbolic paraboloid?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadrics

Obviously, the set of points equidistant to two given skew lines defines a quadric. Is it always a hyperbolic paraboloid?

Comment: There are various easily-found formulas for the distance from a point to a line. Try playing around with some of them to get the equation of a quadric.

Comment: It easy to get to the equation of a quadric, since the difference of the squares of the distances of a point p(x,y,z) to each line is a difference of two polynomials in 3 variables and total degree of two. The question is, how to prove that this quadric is always a hyperbolic paraboloid, as long as the lines are skew.

Comment: Once you have the quadric _explicitly_, it shouldn’t be that difficult to compute its spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two skew lines are characterized by their distance and angle. WLOG (to a similarity transform), let us choose

$$Y=0,Z=1$$ and $$aX+bY=0,Z=0$$ with $a^2+b^2=1$.

The equation of the surface is

$$y^2+(z-1)^2=(ax+by)^2+z^2$$

or

$$2z=a^2(y^2-x^2-2bxy)+1\\=a^2\left(y-\left(b+\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)x\right)\left(y-\left(b-\sqrt{b^2+1}\right)x\right)+1.$$

This is clearly a paraboloid, as $z$ is a quadratic function of $x,y$, and the $z$ cross-sections are hyperbolas.

Comment: I think that you also need $a\ne0$ so that the two lines aren’t parallel.

Comment: @amd: the lines are known to be skew.